# Add Merchant Details to "Buyer" Account

Tags: payment-gateway, balanced-payments

I am using the REST API with C# so I'm not sure how much it will help if I share my code.

I have an `account` whose only `role` is `buyer` and only has 1 credit card linked.

I would like to add the `merchant` role to this `account` by linking a bank account and the necessary merchant information.

If I have the following `account`:

```
{
"holds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/holds",
"name": "John Smith",
"roles": [
    "buyer"
],
"created_at": "2012-11-06T02:54:03.300028Z",
"uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount",
"bank_accounts_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/bank_accounts",
"refunds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/refunds",
"meta": {},
"debits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/debits",
"transactions_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/transactions",
"email_address": "john@smith.com",
"id": "MyAccount",
"credits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/credits",
"cards_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount/cards"
}
```

I understand I can `POST` the following bank account information to the `account`'s `bank_account_uri` to link the bank account to the `account`:

```
{
"name": "WHC III Checking",
"account_number": "12341234",
"bank_code": "321174851"
}
```

The `account` still only shows a single `buyer` `role` after `POST`ing the new bank account information to the `account`'s `bank_account_uri`.

How do I add the `merchant` role to an existing `buyer` `account` using the `Balanced Payments REST API`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some help on the BalancedPayments IRC channel.

This article shows how: [Promote a Buyer Account to a Merchant](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/master/resources/accounts.rst#promote-a-buyer-account-to-a-merchant)

You need to submit a `PUT` request with the merchant details in the body to the `account_uri`

```
PUT /v1/marketplaces/MyMarket/accounts/MyAccount

{
"merchant": {
    "phone_number": "+19046281796",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "name": "jo",
    "dob": "1984-01",
    "state": "CA",
    "postal_code": "94110",
    "type": "person",
    "street_address": "Somewhere over the rainbow",
    "tax_id": "013825400"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Balanced Payments KFC redirect to create a merchant, it will redirect you to the redirect_uri you specify.

It will send back two parameters: an email_address and merchant_uri. You can send a (update) PUT request to the same route Greg mentioned in order to associate an existing account with the merchant.

PUT /v1/marketplaces/your_marketplace_id/accounts/account_id

```
{
  "merchant_uri": "merchant uri goes here"
}
```